# HOW TO: Open Up a Requests Session in Browser

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How do I open a Python Requests session in my browser? I have worked my way through a website using GETS and POSTS, and after doing so I want to open up the URL with all of the information I've sent to the website already sent.

Answer (score 0):

Your information if mainly stored in your cookies. So you can import you cookies which stored in you session to a browser to open the url.

```
from requests.utils import dict_from_cookiejar

cookies = dict_from_cookiejar(s.cookies) # s is your session object
```

then open your browser(like chrome) with your cookies

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# set browser cookies
for key, value in cookies.items():
    driver.add_cookie({'name': key, 'value': value})  # TODO: may be "domain" would also be needed?
```